# Set Django CSRF_TOKEN with yui, but console says 'django.request Forbidden (CSRF token missing or incorrect.)'

Tags: javascript, python, django, yui, django-csrf

I use this code in html:

```
 <script>
  YUI().use('node', function(Y){
      var token = Y.Node.create("{% csrf_token %}");
      YUI.Env.CSRF_TOKEN = token._node.firstChild.getAttribute('value');;
  });
 </script>
```

And I use some javascript code to send POST method:

```
Y.io('http://10.0.3.71/dashboard/send_t2_data', {
        method: 'POST',
        data: {'name':'123456'},
        headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                },
        on: {
            success: function(id, response) {

            },
            failure: function(id, response) {

            }
         }
});
```

But the console says `django.request Forbidden (CSRF token missing or incorrect.): /dashboard/send_t2_data` when I submit all data.

I follow by [the official document](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/model/index.html) to edit YUI.Env.CSRF_TOKEN. But it seems that there is something wrong about my code. Why do I configure the environment variable named `YUI.Env.CSRF_TOKEN` but it does not effective?

Could someone helps me? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not a YUI specialist but it seems you've forgetten the header `X-CSRFToken` with the `csrftoken` cookie.

So get the `csrftoken` cookie dans set the request header `X-CSRFToken` with the value. In pure javascript it gave (copy/paste from a project of mine):

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpResquest();
xhr.open('POST', YOUR-URL, YOU-DATA-AS-STRING);
xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", getCSRFCookie());
xhr.send(null);
```

If I understand your code :

```
Y.io('http://10.0.3.71/dashboard/send_t2_data', {
        method: 'POST',
        data: {'name':'123456'},
        headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'X-CSRFToken': getcookie('csrftoken')
        },
        on: {
            success: function(id, response) {

            },
            failure: function(id, response) {

            }
         }
});
```

where the function `getcookie('csrftoken')` get the cookie named `csrftoken`